# unable to identify object after closing the pop up in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium Webdriver (using Java language) to automate my application. My scenario is that, "Am supposed to click a button on a webpage, it will display the pop up, after I click some buttons in pop up, the pop up will get closed automatically and after that I need to enter some data into the webedit".

Now the issue am facing is that, am not able to enter the value into the webedit after closing the pop up. I am able to enter the value into the same webedit if I directly work with the webedit before I open the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're probably using `driver.switchTo().alert();`. You have to switch back to your original window after closing the alert.</strike>

It sounds like you need to wait for the page to load after closing your popup.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("U_1L_1001"))).click();
```

Comment: No i was not using any switchTo statement in my code.       Without using the code "switchTo" i am able to click the button in the pop up.

Comment: @DeepikaSekar How were you closing the popup then? Please edit your answer with the code used to do so.

Comment: The pop up will have a WebEdit and a submit button. After i enter the value into the WebEdit and click on Submit the pop up will get closed automatically

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("U1_1_L_2121")).click() ---> this is the code to click my Submit button which will automatically close my pop up

Comment: @DeepikaSekar I need more context.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("U1_1L_001")).click()     ---> On clicking this button new pop up window will be opened                                                                     driver.findElement(By.id("U_1L_009")).sendKeys("P78")  ----> I need to enter this P78 text into my webedit which is present in the pop up                               driver.findElement(By.id("U_1_L_2121")).click   ----> This is the submit button. On clicking this button the pop up will get closed

Comment: After that                                 driver.findElement(By.id("U_1L_1001")).sendKeys("2014") ----> I need to enter the value into the edit box after closing the  pop up but this code is throwing error that "ElementNotVisibleException"                                                       But the above code is working fine if i enter the value into the webedit before i work with the pop up

Comment: Just now tried with the wait command as you provided. Got the error "Timed out after 300 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id("")"

Comment: @DeepikaSekar Did you remember to include the id? That error message is telling you that the id was an empty string.

Comment: Yes Yes.. i added the ID during my execution. For eg sake i just posted it without Id

Comment: @DeepikaSekar Do you only have on web driver active?

Comment: Sorry.. I am new to selenium. I could not understand your terms. what is meant by webdriver active.

Comment: @DeepikaSekar Active meaning you constructed it and a browser popped up

Comment: Yes i constructed and a browser popped up as you said

Comment: @DeepikaSekar Do you have more than one open at a time?

Comment: Yes. I will be having two browser at that time apart from my pop up.